# Angular 4 shopping cart functionality onclick to render text

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms

i am new to angular 4 i want to develop a shopping cart functionality with some different render functionality in html. i can't able to find any solution till now.

already tried with jquery append function but it wont work in edit functionality in feature.

Below gif image shows my requirement

[image: Gif Image]

1. if i click any catagory it will directly append to top of the list with selected catagory.
2. Then if i click another catagory for same person it will apply after i click apply button

component.html

```
<ul class="selected-friends" id="appendtext">                

        </ul> 
        <ul class="list-friends" id="listFriends">

            <div *ngFor="let data of result" [attr.id]="'FriendList' + data.id" #item>
                <li class="checkedCatagory">
                    <div class="sf-left">
                        <h3>{{data.fullName}}</h3>
                        <span id="appendCatagoryList"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sf-right">
                        <div class="edit-con sf-icon" data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-target]="'#list' + data.id">
                            <i class="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="del-con sf-icon" [attr.id]="'#list' + data.id" (click)="delete(data.id)">
                            <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>                 
                <!-- Main List started -->

                <li class="mainlistname" data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-target]="'#list' + data.id">
                    <label class="catagory_list" [attr.for]="data.id"><input type="checkbox" [attr.id]="data.id" [attr.value]="data.id">
                    {{data.fullName}}</label>                        
                </li>
                <ul class="sub-friends-list collapse" [attr.id]="'list'+data.id">
                    <p class="mainlistname">Assign Category to this participant</p>
                    <p class="checkedCatagory">Edit or Assign another category to this participant</p>
                    <li *ngFor="let catagoryDetail of catagoryList">
                        <label class="catagory_list">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="catagory_list_checkbox" (click)="resize(data.id, catagoryDetail.id);addToCart(data.id,catagoryDetail.id,data.fullName,catagoryDetail.title)" [value]="catagoryDetail.id" [attr.id]="'catagoryId'+catagoryDetail.id">
                            <span [attr.id]="'catagoryName'+catagoryDetail.id">{{catagoryDetail.title}}</span>
                            <span class="pull-right fnt-16">AED</span>
                            <span class="pull-right fnt-16" id="'fee'+catagoryDetail.id">{{catagoryDetail.fee}}</span>
                            <!-- <p>18-99 Years Male/Female</p> -->
                            <p *ngIf="catagoryDetail.gender === 1">{{catagoryDetail.ageMinMale}}-{{catagoryDetail.ageMaxMale}} Years Male</p>
                            <p *ngIf="catagoryDetail.gender === 2">{{catagoryDetail.ageMinFemale}}-{{catagoryDetail.ageMaxFemale}} Years Female</p>
                            <p *ngIf="catagoryDetail.gender === 3">{{catagoryDetail.ageMinFemale}}-{{catagoryDetail.ageMaxFemale}} Years Male/Female</p>
                        </label>  
                        <span class="checkedCatagoryhidden">
                            <p *ngFor="let catagorySelected of catagoryList" [attr.id]="'catagorySelected'+catagorySelected.id">                                
                                {{catagorySelected.title}} : 
                                <span *ngIf="catagorySelected.gender === 1">{{catagorySelected.ageMinMale}}-{{catagorySelected.ageMaxMale}} Years Male</span>
                                <span *ngIf="catagorySelected.gender === 2">{{catagorySelected.ageMinFemale}}-{{catagorySelected.ageMaxFemale}} Years Female</span>
                                <span *ngIf="catagorySelected.gender === 3">{{catagorySelected.ageMinFemale}}-{{catagorySelected.ageMaxFemale}} Years Male/Female</span>
                                <span class="pull-right fnt-16">AED {{catagorySelected.fee}}</span>                                
                            </p>     
                        </span>                    

                    </li> 
                    <li class="checkedCatagory" class="apply checkedCatagory quantity">
                        <span class="quantity_catagory">Qty: <span [attr.id]="'sectionquantity'+data.id"></span></span>
                        <span class="catagory_amount">Total: AED <span [attr.id]="'sectionprize'+data.id"></span></span>
                        <button class="btnapplyqnty">Apply</button>
                    </li>                           
                </ul>                    
            </div>                
        </ul>
```

component.ts

```
 addToCart(id, catagoryId, fullName, catTitle){
    var currentUserObj = <any>{};
    var self = this;
    var sum;
    currentUserObj[id] = {};    
    currentUserObj[id].participantid = id;
    currentUserObj[id].participantName = fullName;

   // console.log(fullName)
    this.cart.cartItems[id] = {};

    if(jQuery("#catagoryId"+catagoryId).is(":checked")) { 
      currentUserObj[id]['categoryInfo'] = []; 
      currentUserObj[id]['categoryName'] = []; 
      currentUserObj[id]['categoryFee'] = [];
      var totalPrize = 0;
      jQuery('#list'+id).find('.catagory_list input:checked').each(function(){  
        var currentCategoryId = jQuery(this).val();   
        var currentCatagoryName = jQuery('.catagory_list input:checked+#catagoryName'+catagoryId).text();
        currentUserObj[id]['categoryInfo'].push(currentCategoryId);
        currentUserObj[id]['categoryName'].push(jQuery(this).next('').text());
        currentUserObj[id]['categoryFee'].push(Number(jQuery(this).next().next().next().text()));
      });
      sum = currentUserObj[id]['categoryFee'].reduce(this.add, 0);
      currentUserObj[id].quantity = currentUserObj[id]['categoryInfo'].length;
      this.cart.cartItems[id] = currentUserObj[id];     
      currentUserObj[id].participantTotalPrize = sum; 
      console.log('sum',sum)
      this.saveCart();
    } else {
      var currentCategoryId;
      currentUserObj[id]['categoryInfo'] = [];
      currentUserObj[id]['categoryName'] = []; 
      currentUserObj[id]['categoryFee'] = [];
      jQuery('#list'+id).find('.catagory_list input:checked').each(function(){  
        currentCategoryId = jQuery(this).val(); 
        currentUserObj[id]['categoryName'].push(jQuery(this).next().text());
        currentUserObj[id]['categoryInfo'].push(currentCategoryId);      
        currentUserObj[id]['categoryFee'].push(Number(jQuery(this).next().next().next().text()));
      });
      sum = currentUserObj[id]['categoryFee'].reduce(this.add, 0);
      currentUserObj[id].participantTotalPrize = sum;
      currentUserObj[id].quantity = currentUserObj[id]['categoryInfo'].length;      
      this.cart.cartItems[id] = currentUserObj[id];
      if(currentUserObj[id].quantity === 0) {
        console.log("completed delete", this.cart.cartItems[id])
        delete self.cart.cartItems[id];
      }
      this.saveCart();    

    }
  }



  add(a, b) {
      return a + b;
  }

  saveCart() {
      if (window.localStorage) {
        console.log("tfgb",this.cart);
        sessionStorage.setItem('cart',JSON.stringify(this.cart));        
      }
  }

  resize(id, catagoryId) {
    let navObj = this;
    var appendSelectedCatagory = document.getElementById('appendtext'); 
    jQuery(appendSelectedCatagory).prepend(jQuery('#FriendList'+id));

    if(jQuery("#catagoryId"+catagoryId).is(":checked")) { 

        this.displaySelectedList(id, catagoryId);

        var totalPrize = 0;
        navObj.quantity = 0;
       jQuery('#list'+id).find('.catagory_list input:checked').each(function(){   

          var currentCategoryId = jQuery(this).val();      
          navObj.eventRegistrationService.getEventCatagoriesList(navObj.eventId)
          .subscribe((res)=>{
            for(let i in res.data){
            var catList = res.data[i];
              if(catList.id == currentCategoryId){
                totalPrize += catList.fee
                navObj.quantity += 1;                
              }              
            }             
            jQuery('#sectionprize'+id).html(totalPrize);
            jQuery('#sectionquantity'+id).html(navObj.quantity);

          })
        })

    } else {

      this.eventChecked -= 1;
      var totalPrize = 0;
      navObj.quantity = 0;
      jQuery('#list'+id).find('.catagory_list input:checked').each(function(){         
        var currentCategoryId = jQuery(this).val();      
        navObj.eventRegistrationService.getEventCatagoriesList(navObj.eventId)
        .subscribe((res)=>{
          for(let i in res.data){
          var catList = res.data[i];
            if(catList.id == currentCategoryId){
              totalPrize += catList.fee
              navObj.quantity += 1;
            }
          }             
          jQuery('#sectionprize'+id).html(totalPrize)
          jQuery('#sectionquantity'+id).html(navObj.quantity)
        })
      })

      this.checkedCatagory.pop(catagoryId); 
      let checkBoxList = '#appendtext #list'+id;
      if(jQuery(checkBoxList+' :checkbox:checked').length == 0){
        jQuery('#listFriends').append(jQuery('#FriendList'+id));
        jQuery("#FriendList"+id+ " input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false);
        sessionStorage.removeItem(id);
      }

    }    
  }

  displaySelectedList(id, catagoryId){
    this.eventChecked += 1;
    let getselectList = sessionStorage.getItem('selectedFriends');
    jQuery('#appendCatagoryList').append(jQuery('#catagorySelected'+catagoryId))
  }

  delete(id){   
    jQuery('#listFriends').append(jQuery('#FriendList'+id));
    jQuery("#FriendList"+id+ " input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false);
    console.log('asdasdsa',id);
    //this.quantity = 0;
    sessionStorage.removeItem(id);
  }
```

Comment: you need to show the code

Comment: There is not enough detail. As @brk says, show the code. Currently you won't get a better answer than "Use `*ngIf`" and are likely to get downvoted.

Comment: You likely want to have an array of categories selected and use *ngFor to show the categories or as @AluanHaddad said, use *ngIf and show selected categories.

Comment: @brk i have added the code

Comment: You have a lot of repetition that makes your code hard to read. This is an issue in both the template and in the `addToCart` method. Try to factor that out a bit. Ex: `getCatagoryDetail(gender) {return ...`}`. Also, don't use magic numbers. Use strings instead.

Comment: @AluanHaddad above code i have used jquery. but now i want angular 4 code i.e functionality without using jqeury.

Comment: @PrabakaranV that is good. You will find that the resulting code is more declarative, easier to reason about, and more composable. Good luck!

Comment: @PrabakaranV have you got some solution? I am using angular 5 and want to build same thing like you but without any jQuery